# WSO2 api manager not showing destination adress in API Usage by Destination

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I'm using WSO2 AM 2.0.
I'm using dynamic endpoint throught custom sequence.
The problem is that my endpoint destination adress  is not showing now 
I have verifyed that it is insert empty in my analytics DB.
Is there any way to add this information?

Comment: Could you elaborate more with screenshots or sample scenario? Question is not informative.

Comment: When publishing an API throught the publisher portal,in the implement step, I have choosen a dynamic endpoint as Endpoint Type and enabled Enable Message Mediation (in flow).
I have enabled analyitics and when calling my API,I have notice that the field **destination** in the statistics table **api_destination_summary*** is empty for this API.
For ,the others published API with static endpoint (static production and sandbox environment)this information is present.
I hope this more clear Lahiru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom sequence, please set another property named "ENDPOINT_ADDRESS" with the same value as the one you assign to "To" header. It will solve your problem. 
For consequent invokes, the destination address will be set correctly. 
ex:

```html
<header name="To" value="https://localhost:9448/am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api/menu"/>

<property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS" value="https://localhost:9448/am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api/menu"/>
```

Comment: Great Thanks Erandi :)